# Get app initialized firebase instance in front GUI in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, service-worker

I'm new to service workers and firebase web with javascript. I want to retrieve payloads from firebase to show it via a notification to the user. Now I'm struggling with the following problem.

**What works**

When I using the following script to register a service worker, I will get a `succeeded` response.

***index.html***

```
<p id="status"></p>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        // Override the default scope of '/' with './', so that the registration applies
        // to the current directory and everything underneath it.
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {scope: './'}).then(function (registration) {
            // At this point, registration has taken place.
            // The service worker will not handle requests until this page and any
            // other instances of this page (in other tabs, etc.) have been
            // closed/reloaded.
            document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'succeeded';

        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Something went wrong during registration. The service-worker.js file
            // might be unavailable or contain a syntax error.
            document.querySelector('#status').textContent = error;
        });
    } else {
        // The current browser doesn't support service workers.
        var aElement = document.createElement('a');
        aElement.href = 'http://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq';
        aElement.textContent = 'unavailable';
        document.querySelector('#status').appendChild(aElement);
    }
</script>
```

***sw.js***

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "project-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "project-xxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

**What's the problem**

Now my problem is, that I want to handle with the `messaging` constant from the service worker on the index.html because the console tells me that the following script only works in the window context:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a
>   Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window).

```
messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.' + messaging.getToken());

        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (currentToken) {
                 if (currentToken) {
                     console.log(currentToken);
                 } else {
                     // Show permission request.
                     console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                     // Show permission UI.
                 }
             })
             .catch(function (err) {
                 console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
             });
         })
         .catch(function (err) {
             console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
         });
```

Now how can I get the firebase instance from the registration or is that a wrong theory?

Answer (score 0):

The window context is not available to the Service Worker. It's also not possible to share anything from the window to the SW and vice versa (so you cannot declare a variable and access it from both). From the error message, it seems that the Firebase libraries depend upon the window context so you cannot use them inside ths SW script.

I'm not sure how to handle what you're trying to do.